# Raspberry pi zero android bluetooth tethering

Tags: raspberry-pi-zero

I am trying to setup a bluetooth tethering from my raspberry to my android phone. I have them paired through bluetoothctl, and when I run `sudo rfcomm watch hci0`, I can open up Bluetooth Terminal app on my phone and connect. When I type anything, it will echo it back to me, which is weird, but it means, that they are connected.

When I open bluetooth settings on my phone, open raspberry, there should be a button "Internet access: Allow internet through tethering, as it does when I open my paired laptop. It doesn't. What should I do?

I tried http://blog.kugelfish.com/2012/10/look-ma-no-wires-raspberry-pi-bluetooth.html, but when installing the packages, it says that they are obsolete, and package blues doesn't provide the `pand` command.

Thanks for any answer